# Access to localhost with nginx and docker-compose

Tags: nginx, localhost, docker-compose

I would like access to my local app on localhost url with docker-compose and nginx. I can access to my projet with 127.0.0.1 and my vhost app.local, but not with localhost : error 404.

My nginx conf (symfony project) :

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 app.local;
    root /var/www/app/web;
    location ~ ^(.*)/(app|app_dev|app_test|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
}
```

Anyone have idea why i can't access to my app with localhost ?

Thank you !

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's linux based, did you add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Hi mickadoo! I'm sorry, I did not specify my environment :/ I'm on Windows 10 :)

Comment: Hmm, have you had problems accessing localhost before? It's strange you get a 404, is that a browser error, like it can't find your Symfony app at all, or it is 404 from Symfony - like "route not found"

Comment: No problem for access of my localhost if i use NodeJS, for example. And it's 404 nginx, not Symfony app.

Comment: I tried running an nginx container using the same config you have. It showed me the content I had in the server root. You don't have any other nginx containers running, or any webserver on your host machine do you?  I'm not sure I can help you here, but I'll upvote you for attention

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm at a total brick wall trying to do the same...